# Apex Batch: Query locator failure

Tags: apex, batch, class, schedulebatch

I am facing an issue with the querylocator line here. My code snippet as below.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      query = 'select Id,(select Name from Call2_vod__r where Signature_Date_vod__c !=Null and Account_vod__c not in :existMap.keySet() limit 1) from Account';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);}
```

> Error: |FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a right
>   parentheses, found '(' Class.Account_chk_batch.start: line 5, column 1

Line5 is return statement here.Can someone please help?

Comment: Not sure whether '(' mark need to be escaped or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly it is this code that doesn't run inside developer console. Try a slight change and see if this works for you.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
set<string> keys = existMap.keySet();
      query = 'select Id,(select Name from Call2_vod__r where Signature_Date_vod__c !=Null and Account_vod__c not in :keys limit 1) from Account';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);}
```

I've just replaced the `existMap.keySet()` in the query to a set with the keys in. Looks like a problem with the query with the () inside.

Comment: See the "simple bind variables" mention in the [Dynamic SOQL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) documentation for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks Richard! It's working. But it is taking long time to complete batch run. Will let you know about this.:)

Comment: I am sorry Richard. It is showing below error.

Comment: Error:First error: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Comment: You'll probably need a where clause on your main select (from Account). Try the query in developer console and see what's returned.